# plotly express plot not shown in jupyter notebook

Tags: express, plotly

I am using plotly express and just copied the official example from the below website in my jupyter notebook. The plot didn't show after running fig.show().

https://plot.ly/python/plotly-express/

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
fig.show()
```

I did install pip3 install dash==1.8.0

I am using python 3.5

Thanks for your help.

Regards

---

Update:

I think i have to run it from .py file directly instead of using jupyter notebook. It works sometimes. Sometime, it doesn't work after opening a new browser. The error say:

This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

not sure what is the problem?

anyone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to install `ipywidgets`.

`$ pip install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.2"`

or if you use conda

`$ conda install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.2"`

Then relaunch your Jupyter notebook.

See the [getting started](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/) official documentation (section Jupyter Notebook Support).